# exact percentage change for the estimated COOP effect

Tags: regression, self-study, econometrics

An regression output from STATA

```
reg lnQ lnL lnK COOP

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =      87
-------------+------------------------------           F(  3,    83) =  177.43
       Model |  46.8044524     3  15.6014841           Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |  7.29838834    83   .08793239           R-squared     =  0.8651
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.8602
       Total |  54.1028407    86  .629102799           Root MSE      =  .29653

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         lnQ |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         lnL |   .7682515   .0662688    11.59   0.000     .6364455    .9000576
         lnK |   .0537095   .0495861     1.08   0.282    -.0449153    .1523342
        COOP |   -.158698   .0660776    -2.40   0.019    -.2901238   -.0272723
       _cons |   4.946906   .2614977    18.92   0.000     4.426797    5.467014


    firm            float   %9.0g                 firm code (or firm ID)
    va              float   %9.0g                 value added in millions of lire
    labor           float   %9.0g                 permanent employees at year end
    capital         float   %9.0g                 fixed assets at historical cost in millions of lire
COOP = a dummy variable for a worker cooperative. Conventional firms have code (or ID) numbers (given by FIRM) less than 100, while the code (or ID) numbers for worker cooperatives exceed 99.
COOP_LNL=COOP*lnL
    lnQ = the natural logarithm of output (value added)
lnL = the natural logarithm of labor
lnK = the natural logarithm of capital
```

I am asked to calculate the exact percentage change for the estimated COOP effect. I am wondering how does it differ from the interpretation that each additional unit of COOP is associated with 15.9% less in output (less say,  lnQ is output), if any?

Comment: Is COOP a dummy variable?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov: just update my post...COOP is a dummy variable.

Comment: Searching our site turns up many variations of this question, such as interpreting interacting categorical variables when taking the log of the dependent variable: http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=log%20regression%20interpretation%20coefficient%20dummy.

Comment: Take a look at [here](http://davegiles.blogspot.com/2011/03/dummies-for-dummies.html) and report back if this is not clear.